# Call custom ModelBinder in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-binding

I'm creating a custom ModelBinder in .NET Core 1.1.0, and I think I have it mostly figured out. I want to use this binder only when I specifically want to, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this. I want this model binder to be ignored when I don't call it, but when I call it I want all *others* to be ignored. How can I accomplish this?

The two things that seem feasible are the parameter attributes [`[Bind]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindattribute) and [`[ModelBinder]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinderattribute), but neither of these really works.

I first tried the below:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([Bind("test")] int userId)
{
    // stuff
}
```

When my custom [`IModelBinderProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinderprovider) is hit, the [`ModelBinderProviderContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbinderprovidercontext) contains a [`BindingInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindinginfo) property, which in turn contains an [`IPropertyFilterProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.ipropertyfilterprovider). When debugging, that filter provider contains a collection called `Include` with my value of `test`. There doesn't appear to be any way to check for that programmatically, however--there's no way that I can find to actually access that collection. It's null if nothing is set, so I could hypothetically check for null, but that's very messy and isn't a good idea.

To illustrate, here's the debugger info for the [`ModelBinderProviderContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbinderprovidercontext):

[image: debugger output]

Next, I tried using this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))] int userId
)
{
    // stuff
}
```

This attribute appears to have no effect whatsoever. It does not force `MyModelBinder` to be used; model binders are used in the order specified in `Startup.cs` (the list in [`MvcOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_MvcOptions_ModelBinderProviders)).

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyFilterProvider` contains a [`BindAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4cca6b09f0044660d64469e3278b584a17c356e9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BindAttribute.cs) instance which implements the `IPropertyFilterProvider` interface. You could cast the instance to a `BindAttribute` and access the `Include` property:

```
var bindAttribute = context.BindingInfo.PropertyFilterProvider as BindAttribute;
var include = bindAttribute?.Include;
```

Keep in mind that the cast may not succeed, resulting in `bindingAttribute` being `null`.